# Issue with menu in Safari for windows and IE

Tags: css, windows, internet-explorer, safari

I have a problem with safari for windows moving images around. Can anyone help?

The menu does not seem to work at all in IE - I'm not sure what  to do about that either!

[Here's the page with the problem](http://www.playlistforlife.org.uk/test/index.html)

and here's the CSS where I suspect the problem with safari is:

```
    #nav ul {
background:#FFFFFF;
height:auto;
padding:10px 0;
position:absolute;
top:-125px;
width:180px;
z-index:-1;

transition:0.8s ease-in-out;
box-shadow:2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-moz-box-shadow:2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-moz-transition:0.8s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:0.8s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition:all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}
#nav ul li {
width:180px;

}
#nav ul li a {
background:transparent;
height:20px;
line-height:20px;
width:180px;
}
#nav:hover {
height:200px;
}
#nav li:hover ul {
-moz-transform:translate(0,161px); /*some css3*/
-o-transform:translate(0,161px);
-webkit-transform:translate(0,161px);
}
#nav a:hover,#nav li:hover > a {
color:#6d6e71;
}
```

Comment: You haven't added any transitions / transforms for IE. I believe that these are unprefixed for IE.

Comment: Always *always* specify the unprefixed version as well for any prefixed CSS you use.

Comment: Thank you that's really helpful. I think that's the issue with IE fixed:) Any ideas about the safari for windows problem?